# how to get a sentiment score (and keep the sentiment words) in quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

Consider this simple example

```
library(tibble)
library(quanteda)

tibble(mytext = c('this is a good movie',
                  'oh man this is really bad',
                  'quanteda is great!'))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  mytext                   
  <chr>                    
1 this is a good movie     
2 oh man this is really bad
3 quanteda is great!
```

I would like to perform some basic sentiment analysis, but with a twist. Here is my dictionary, stored into a regular `tibble`

```
mydictionary <- tibble(sentiment = c('positive', 'positive','negative'),
                       word = c('good', 'great', 'bad'))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  sentiment word 
  <chr>     <chr>
1 positive  good 
2 positive  great
3 negative  bad
```

Essentially, I would like to count how many positive and negative words are detected in each sentence, but also keep track of the matching words. In other words, the output should look like

```
                          mytext nb.pos nb.neg   pos.words
1 this is a good and great movie      2      0 good, great
2      oh man this is really bad      0      1         bad
3             quanteda is great!      1      0       great
```

How can I do that in `quanteda`? Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay tuned for **quanteda** v. 2.1 in which we will have greatly expanded, dedicated functions for sentiment analysis.  In the meantime, see below.  Note that I made some adjustments since there is a discrepancy in what you report as the text and your input text, also you have all sentiment words in `pos.words`, not just positive words.  Below, I compute both positive and all sentiment matches.

```r
# note the amended input text
mytext <- c(
  "this is a good and great movie",
  "oh man this is really bad",
  "quanteda is great!"
)

mydictionary <- tibble::tibble(
  sentiment = c("positive", "positive", "negative"),
  word = c("good", "great", "bad")
)

library("quanteda", warn.conflicts = FALSE)
## Package version: 2.0.9000
## Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

# make the dictionary into a quanteda dictionary
qdict <- as.dictionary(mydictionary)
```

Now we can use the lookup functions to get to your final data.frame.

```r
# get the sentiment scores
toks <- tokens(mytext)
df <- toks %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = qdict) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  convert(to = "data.frame")
names(df)[2:3] <- c("nb.neg", "nb.pos")

# get the matches for pos and all words
poswords <- tokens_keep(toks, qdict["positive"])
allwords <- tokens_keep(toks, qdict)

data.frame(
  mytext = mytext,
  df[, 2:3],
  pos.words = sapply(poswords, paste, collapse = ", "),
  all.words = sapply(allwords, paste, collapse = ", "),
  row.names = NULL
)
##                           mytext nb.neg nb.pos   pos.words   all.words
## 1 this is a good and great movie      0      2 good, great good, great
## 2      oh man this is really bad      1      0                     bad
## 3             quanteda is great!      0      1       great       great
```

Comment: thank you ken! this is great! In my real-life example, I have several million rows. Do you think this would be the correct way to proceed even with that many sentences?

Comment: and looking forward to that `v 2.1` !  When is the release scheduled?

Comment: Think so, yes - I've used this on 6-10 million Tweet corpora before. If you run into bottlenecks, feel free to report a GitHub issue so we can focus on the problem.